# Programmable Logic Array (PLA) Design

Tags: logic, digital-design

I need to design Programmable Logic Array (PLA) circuit with given functions. How can I design circuit with POS form functions. Can someone explain that?  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Lqy.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about programming

Answer (score 0):

Below is the design process completed for F, the other two outputs, G and H, can done in a similar fashon.

```
F Truth Table
A  B  C  D  #  F G H
0  0  0  0  0  1
0  0  0  1  1  0
0  0  1  0  2  0
0  0  1  1  3  1
0  1  0  0  4  1
0  1  0  1  5  1
0  1  1  0  6  0
0  1  1  1  7  0
1  0  0  0  8  0
1  0  0  1  9  0
1  0  1  0  10 1
1  0  1  1  11 1
1  1  0  0  12 0
1  1  0  1  13 0
1  1  1  0  14 1
1  1  1  1  15 1
```

F Karnaugh Map:

```
AB\CD   00   01   11   10
   \
                 
            ----------
00       0  | 1 x  1 |  0
            ----------
        --------
01     | 1 y  1 |  0    0
        --------
                 ----------
11       0    0  | 1    1 |
                 |   z    |
                 |        |
10       0    0  | 1    1 |
                 ----------
```

F Sum Of Product Boolean:

```
(A'B'D)+(A'BC')+(AC)
   x      y       z   ==>(for ref):
                            x=(A'B'D)
                            y=(A'BC')
                            z=(AC)
```

F Logic Circuit:

```
                  -------                        ------ 
        A---NOT---|     |   -------              |    |
                  | AND |---|     |              |    |
        B---NOT---|     |   | AND | x            |    |
                  -------   |     |--------------|    |
D---------------------------|     |              |    |
                            -------              |    |
                                                 |    | F
                  -------                        | OR |---
        A---NOT---|     |   -------   ------     |    |
                  | AND |---|     | y |    |     |    |
        C---NOT---|     |   | AND |---|    |     |    |
                  -------   |     |   |    | y+z |    |
B---------------------------|     |   |    |-----|    |
                            -------   | OR |     |    |
          -------                     |    |     |    |
A---NOT---|     | z                   |    |     |    |
          | AND |---------------------|    |     ------
C---NOT---|     |                     |    |
          -------                     |    |
                                      ------
```